# How to perform AND operator in a C# regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have two regular expressions that are being used for different purposes.

```
^(?:(?!(?:abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz|012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)'\'1{2})).)
```

This regex is for controlling that a string can't contain 3 consecutive characters like **abc**, **123**

```
^['\'x20-\x7E]+$
```

And this regex is for controlling that a string can't contain non-english characters like **ş**, **ü**, **ı**, **ğ**,...

I would like to combine these two rules. Both of them must be performed. I tried to add an AND operator to between them but **&** isn't allowed.

How can i do this? Are there any operator in regex substitutes of **&**? If there aren't, How can i do this same job by different ways?

EDIT: Someone can't get my question so I decided to explain in more details.

```
(^(((?:abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz|012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)'\'1{2})).)*|^['\'x20-\x7E]+$)
```

You can try this regex from https://regex101.com/

This is not working the way i want. 3 consecutive characters aren't allowed ok but it is not checking non-english characters. For example if you type ğğğ That will be accepted. I put | operator between them. It's wrong I know. I gotta put AND operator but I don't know How can AND operator be used in a regular expression? That's actually the main problem.

Comment: Are you sure you really need a regular expression?

Comment: Yes It will be easier way for me

Comment: Could you provide example input and output? "abc" should fail because there are 3 letters? Or alphanumerics?

Comment: Well, think about it again. Already your regex is awful. I guess you may need a simple procedural code.

Comment: Each of them are working well. For example: abc is fail, 123 is fail or ğckl is fail. I just want to combine them. Because I will add it to model class. Model class doesn't allow using 2 regex at the same time. The must be in the same regex.

Comment: What do you mean by non-English characters? I'm not aware of a character set defined as English. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_terms_with_diacritical_marks shows that there are many English phrases with diacritics, so I suppose it can't mean that.

Comment: Can't you just feed the result from one regex into the source for the second regex?

Comment: @Graham yes i want to explain them in one regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
^(?!.*(?:abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz|012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|([\da-z])\1{2}))[\x20-\x7E]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hW4uI0/2)

Comment: Thank you very very much. There aren't any answer on the internet for this problem and I think, you probably solved it first. I have been trying for one week. Thank you very very much again.