# Java - regex to match successive digits or character in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a client requirement that while choosing the password the user can't use more then three successive characters or digits in the password string. For example:

```
abc ->> allowed
abcd ->> not allowed
wxy ->> allowed
wxyz ->> not allowed
stu ->> allowed
stuv ->> not allowed
```

and to be specific ab, bc, kl, op these are allowed. I mean successive digits or characters are allowed up to length three. And any thing more then three length(successive) is not allowed. Like 12345, 123456, 456789, abcdef, pqrstuv - these are not allowed.

and same goes for digits. Examples:

```
123 ->> allowed
1234 ->> not allowed
456 ->> allowed
4567 ->> not allowed
345 ->> allowed
3456 ->> not allowed
```

and 12, 45, 78, 89 these are allowed.

Is it achievable with regex? If so then a little help is needed.

I have tried the following regex :

```
^(?:(?!(?:abcd|bcde|cdef|defg|efgh|fghi|ghij|hijk|ijkl|jklm|klmn|lmno|mnop|nopq|opqr|pqrs|qrst|rstu|stuv|tuvw|uvwx|vwxy|wxyz|(a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)\1{3})).)*
```

but this regex doesn't give the proper out put. Like it founds a match for both the strings "abc" and "acm".

For testing my regex I am using the following regex tester:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Would definitely not go with regex for that, as you'd basically have to hardcode sequences, just as your example shows. Instead I'd parse the whole `String` for character code point increments and set a counter blowing up stuff when that increment is by one for `x` number of successive instances.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509483/how-to-perform-and-operator-in-a-c-sharp-regex

Comment: Just to make sure, is `abef` allowed?

Comment: `abef` is allowed @Pshemo

Comment: Then duplicate question contains regex answer, but I agree with others that this is not task for regex. You should write your own method which will iterate over your string searching for continues characters/digits.

Comment: the duplicate question has the answer for the repetition part. But not for this one @Pshemo

Answer (score 1):

I think this sort of thing is best done in code rather than a regex. I'd just use Character.isLetter(c) and cast your chars to ints to see if they are in sequence.

Comment: in my scenario I have to do it with regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick, dirty , non-optimized (and possibly buggy) but self-contained example of what you're trying to achieve.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // should not allow
    System.out.println(hasValidSequence("abcd", 3));
    // should not allow
    System.out.println(hasValidSequence("1234", 3));
    // should allow
    System.out.println(hasValidSequence("abcd", 4));
    // should allow
    System.out.println(hasValidSequence("1234", 4));
}
public static boolean hasValidSequence(String input, int maxAllowed) {
    // boilerplate validation of empties/nulls
    if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
        // TODO handle better?
        return false;
    }
    // counter for blowing things up if reached
    int counter = 0;
    // char takes int values - initializing as bogus 0
    char c = (char)0;
    // iterating input String characters one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        // previous char is next char as int, - 1 --> they're successive
        // you can fool around and replace with input.charAt(i) <= i 
        // for indirect sequences or same characters
        // TODO check it's an alpha numeric!
        if (c == input.charAt(i) - 1) {
            // incrementing counter
            counter++;
        }
        // assigning current char
        c = input.charAt(i);
        // counter reached? we blow things up!
        if (counter == maxAllowed) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // no counter reached, return true
    return true;
}
```

**Output**

```
false
false
true
true
```